# Can I transfer files from to GoPro 3 to my PC over Wifi?

Tags: gopro, gopro-wifi, wifi-transfer

There's an android / IOS [app](http://gopro.com/support/gopro-app-support) which connects to the GoPro3's WiFi to let you change settings, preview, and function the camera -- but it doesn't allow you to transfer the files. (Also I want to transfer them to my pc)

**Is there an application for windows which will let me wirelessly transfer files from my gopro?**

Answer (score 23):

The gopro runs its own web server (cherokee). To show the files and 'download' to your pc/mac/phone/etc simply point your browser to:

```
http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/
```

As mentioned above, the transfer speeds are quite slow, it's still usable.

Note: This is for gopro hero 2 with wifi bacpack, may be different for other devices.

Comment: Works for Hero 3 black as well. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work with Hero 3+ Black Edition?

Comment: @Kozuch Yes, it does. I tested it just now.

Answer (score 2):

GoPro have recently updated their [IOS/Android App](http://gopro.com/support/cineform-studio-software-support) to allow you to transfer directly to your device, including Dropbox sync.
Pretty neat stuff!

Answer (score 1):

[WiGo](http://cam-do.com/WiGo/) by cam-do.com claims to let you do this.

I tried it out. Windows noted that I was connected at 65mbps, however the file file transfer was horribly slow.

I was trying to transfer 3 files at a total of 5GB, and over about 5 minutes, only one file transferred 65mb. It would have taken hours at that rate to transfer the files (and instead of charging the battery, like using a cable would -- this was draining the battery).

FYI the UI is neat and simple, it's a great app for changing the settings etc, and it fires up a VLC streaming preview.
Browsing the filesystem is done via a web server, you browse it like a webpage and "download" the files.

I also noted that going to help->about states that it expires in 25 days...