# How do I wirelessly transfer data from a GoPro Hero4 to a Mac?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, transfer, gopro-wifi

I can get my Hero4 to wirelessly transfer files to my Ipad using the GoPro app, but I can't seem to do the same to my computer. Is there a way I can get these files transferred wirelessly to my Mac?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/546628/can-i-transfer-files-from-to-gopro-3-to-my-pc-over-wifi

Answer (score 5):

You can simply connect to your GoPro's WiFi and get to http://10.5.5.9:8080/ with your browser. This takes you to the GoPro's HTTP-server where you can download all files.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing and tried accessing using the browser but it didn't give me many options when downloading. So I develop a simple app to do the job. It is called GPConnect and can be downloaded from [macupdate](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/55909/gpconnect) website. It is a free app.

Kareem